# Нужна помощь в API

Tags: wordpress, api, get

Абсолютный ноль в API, но есть сайт футбольной школы, где нужно сделать список мероприятий. Было найдено решение с этим API https://api.analyticom.de/swagger-ui.html#!/COMET_DB_Export_API/exportCompetitionsUsingGET

Но не имею ни малейшего представления как вставить это на страницу сайта. Что надо делать?

Есть другой сайт, который использовал такую же API и у них получилось так: http://online.lff.lv/competitions/virsliga-2017-954518/

Направьте на верный путь, с чего начинать вообще?

Answer (score 0):

API, грубо говоря, штука, позволяющая получить данные.
Т.е. вы по определенному урлу отсылаете определенный JSON, а в ответ вам приходит другой JSON, который вы обрабатываете.

Начать стоит с изучение JSON. После, скорее всего, вам придется изучить JS (что бы нарисовать то, что вы получили).